# Google Earth for Android will not draw line across International Date Line

Tags: android, kml, google-earth

I have a kmz that breaks across the International Date Line. It works in Google Earth for Windows and iOS, but it does not work in Google Earth for Android 8.0.1.2310. I think that it is an issue in Google Earth for Android.

Here is a link to the file: http://www.johnfbell.com/kmz/DELTA_159_11OCT_2014_DTW-ICN_RLS_1_no_TP_Airports_Terrain_NAT_RADAR_NWS_Warn.kmz

Separate problem, same file. The equator is a line within Google Earth, but does not show on the Android. It shows on the PC and iOS.

If it is a Google Earth for Android issue, is this the best venue to report it?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried going from 178 to 182 longitude (made up numbers) instead of 178 to -178 longitude and this does not fix it.